# Вывод данных из БД.

Tags: php

Достаю последние 20 данных из бд

```
$text_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatText ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 0, 20") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($text_chat))
{
}
```

И выводится в виде 
30 
29
28
и т.д.

Как вывести последние 20 вот так
и т.д.
28
29
30

Comment: уберите DESC :)

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18567722/815386

     SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM ChatText ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 0, 20)sub ORDER BY id ASC;

мопед не мой

Comment: Спасибо работает.

Comment: Только вы указываете SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM ChatText ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 0, 20) ORDER BY id ASC; Там ещё sub добавить нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM ChatText") or die(mysql_error());
$last = mysql_result($result,0); 
$last -= 20;
if($last < 0)
    $last = 0;
$text_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatText ORDER BY `id` limit ".$last.", 20") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($text_chat))
{
}
```

Тут вы сначала подсчитываете кол-во строк в таблице, отнимаете от него 20, и в итоге начинаете считывание с н-ной строки, и получаете последних 20 строк в обычном порядке.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-14, 20' at line 1

Comment: Нет 39 )))

Comment: @Vlmake Чёрт. Я понял ошибку. Я просто напрямую давно не использую команды MySQL. Всё через функции. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @Vlmake Пробуйте. Как результат?